# OpenGL 3/4 support in D

Tags: d

Is there any lib that provides OpenGL 3 or 4 bindings for the D language? AFAIK, derelict only gives 2.1 capabilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

derelict2 supports OpenGL 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 and 4.0.

See http://www.dsource.org/projects/derelict/changeset?old=branches%2FDerelict2%2FDerelictGL%2Fderelict%2Fopengl%40523&new=branches%2FDerelict2%2FDerelictGL%2Fderelict%2Fopengl%40523

The link above is not longer working.
Derelict is now version 3 and on Github: https://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3/

Comment: thanks. I didn't notice that and thought derelict still stuck at 2.1

Comment: You might also want to read this post which explains how to load the more modern versions: http://www.dsource.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4531&sid=0fcab7e56eecfbd446567746802bfcea

Comment: Hey Guys the links to derelict are not working anymore. Anybody knows why?

Comment: After a search I've found out that DErelict is now on version 3 and moved to GitHub.
Here's the link https://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3/